# how to validate each json elements

Tags: php, json

How do i validate each **json** elements?

```
[
  {"FirmId":"1","ProductCode":"1","TotalStock":"16"},
  {"TotalStock":"0"},
  {"FirmId":"1","ProductCode":"12461","TotalStock":"0"},
  {"FirmId":"1","ProductCode":"12462","TotalStock":"0"},
  {"FirmId":"1","ProductCode":"12463","TotalStock":"10"}
]
```

in above json element no.2 is different than all others, it should be equal.
how to know that?
is there any inbuild function?

Comment: Validate what? That each item has a certain key/keys?

Comment: Its 1 not 2, arrays are base 0 in PHP.  You could use something like !isset($array[1]['FirmId'])

Comment: Possible with "array_diff_key" method. The logic could be to loop through all the json and extract the possible keys of one object. And then loop again to compare each object keys with extracted keys using "array_diff_key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to validate these elements, here I have added two methods just give you some idea.

By assuming element count is fixed (= 3)

```
function check1($obj) {
  foreach($obj as $elm) {
   if(count($elm) != 3) {
     echo 0 . PHP_EOL; 
    }
     echo 1 . PHP_EOL;;
    }
  }
```

Using general key

```
function check2($obj, $key) {
    foreach($obj as $elm) {
      if(!array_key_exists($key, $elm)) {
       echo 0 . PHP_EOL; 
      }
      echo 1 . PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
```